# How to call String.Split that takes string as separator?

Tags: c#, string

I have following string value:   `AnnualFee[[ContactNeeYear` that I want to split using separator : `"[["`

The MSDN topic [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) says that such function exists, so i used following code :

`oMatch.Groups[0].Value.Split('[[');`

but it throws an error saying:

> Can not implicitly convert string[] to string

so how to split string value with separator : `"[["`

Comment: Please give your question a meaningful title avoiding general terms such as *issue* or *problem*.

Comment: the `oMatch.Groups[0]` is probably an array itself. and you should use `Split("[[")` instead of single quotations.

Comment: @arianoo - `Groups[0]` is the first element of the array `Groups`, so that's not the issue.  The error message states what the problem is - the `Split` function is expecting a string array of delimiters, not a single delimiter.

Comment: @arianoo I think you're right about the double and single quotes... I'd put that as an answer, that should solve it I think

Comment: I've updated your title/post - feel free to revert/improve.

Answer (score 4):

Try below code, it has worked for me:

```
        string abc = "AnnualFee[[ContactNeeYear";

        string[] separator = { "[[" };

        string[] splitedValues = abc.Split(separator , StringSplitOptions.None);
```

I hope it will help you.. :):)

Answer (score 2):

```
string text= "AnnualFee[[ContactNeeYear";
string[] parts= Regex.Split(text, @"\[\[");
```

The result is:

```
AnnualFee
ContactNeeYear
```

You can use Regex.Split(text, pattern) for such purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In a short way ,

```
string yourString = "AnnualFee[[ContactNeeYear";  
string [] _split = yourString.Split(new string[] { "[[" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```